# Writing Chinese text using "CJKutf8" package. Sample is shown below. "textbf{}" not working on Chinese text. Heading of abstract isn't bold too

Tags: overleaf, latex3

```
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\begin{chineseabstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\chineseabstractname}
```

中文摘要写在这里 (Chinese abstract is written here)

```
\textbf{关键词:}
\end{chineseabstract}  
\clearpage\end{CJK*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Use `polyglossia` with `ucharclasses`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{chinese}
\newfontfamily{\cjkfont}{Source Han Sans}[BoldFont ={* Bold}, ItalicFont={* Light}, BoldItalicFont={* Heavy}]
\usepackage[CJK]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionsForCJK{\cjkfont}{}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\textbf{关键词:}\\
\textchinese{中文摘要写在这里}.

\end{document}
```